# Using Try and Except to allow bad input still stores the bad input

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to get user input to store some numbers and print out the largest and smallest number. I need to have an except in my code that will print an error message then continue to print my numbers. The problem I am having is if I type a word like cat to get the error message, it also makes the word my largest number. I just want my error message followed by my 2 numbers

```py
l = None
s = None
while True:
    num = input('Enter your number')

    if num == 'done':
        break
    try:
        num=float(num)

    except:
        print('Invalid input')

    if l is None:
        l = num
    elif num > l:
        l = num
    if s is None:
        s =  num
    if num < s:
        s = num         
print('Maximum is ',l)
print('Minimum is ',s)
```

any help will be great thanks alot

Comment: not sure why my code wont paste correct

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `continue` right after your `print('invalid input')`. That will make it start the loop again and ask for another number from the user.

Comment: No problem! Glad it worked for you. Please mark the answer as accepted. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers